# How to display my name and the icon menu on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10

How to display my username or my real name and the icon menu on ubuntu 13.10 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command to display your name on unity top panel,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

After that logout and login back.

Answer (score 2):

To do that and other tweaks, you can use the Unity Tweak Tool.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: By far the best way to accomplish this. Nice tool set.